# How to do something on pageload in jQuery AND onclick after?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript:

```
// when page LOADS:
// update PassMark score
$("#passmark").attr("onclick", "window.open('https://www.google.ca/search?num=20&q=site%3Avideocardbenchmark.net+" + encodeURIComponent( $("input[name='vc_gpu_engine']").val() ).replace(/%20/g, "+") + "', 'url', 'status,scrollbars=yes,height=900,width=1050').focus();");

// if any field is changed AFTER the page loads, then run these
$("body").click(function() {

  // update PassMark score
  $("#passmark").attr("onclick", "window.open('https://www.google.ca/search?num=20&q=site%3Avideocardbenchmark.net+" + encodeURIComponent(     $("input[name='vc_gpu_engine']").val() ).replace(/%20/g, "+") + "', 'url', 'status,scrollbars=yes,height=900,width=1050').focus();");

});
```

Now like any programmer, I like to keep code to a minimum.

Is there a way to avoid duplicating the same command?

Can I run the same line of code both when page loads and when the user clicks anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var func = function () {
    $("#passmark").attr("onclick", "window.open('https://www.google.ca/search?num=20&q=site%3Avideocardbenchmark.net+" + encodeURIComponent($("input[name='vc_gpu_engine']").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+") + "', 'url', 'status,scrollbars=yes,height=900,width=1050').focus();");
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    func();
    $("body").click(function () {
        func();
    });
});
```

This way you can use the `func()` afterwards as well.

**EDIT** *Even Shorter*

```
var func = function () {
    $("#passmark").attr("onclick", "window.open('https://www.google.ca/search?num=20&q=site%3Avideocardbenchmark.net+" + encodeURIComponent($("input[name='vc_gpu_engine']").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+") + "', 'url', 'status,scrollbars=yes,height=900,width=1050').focus();");
}

$(function(){
  func();
  $("body").click(func);
});
```

Comment: I like the modularity of this code - refactoring at it's finest.

Answer (score 0):

Bind event handler and trigger it immediately:

```
$("body").click(function() {

    // update PassMark score
    $("#passmark").attr("onclick", "window.open('https://www.google.ca/search?num=20&q=site%3Avideocardbenchmark.net+" + encodeURIComponent( $("input[name='vc_gpu_engine']").val() ).replace(/%20/g, "+") + "', 'url', 'status,scrollbars=yes,height=900,width=1050').focus();");

}).click();
```